# Equation for calculate right triangle's third point, Other 2 points and all three sides are known

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, tangent-line, tangent-line-method

I am having right triangle. Length of all sides of this triangle are known. Two vertices from three of triangle are known. I want to calculate third vertex which is creating right angle in this triangle. what equation or formula i can use to calculate this point. below is graphical representation of my problem. Please help.

[image]

Known values are:

- Point P(px, py)
- Point O(cx, cy)
- Angle PTO = 90°
- side PT
- side OP
- side OT
- Point B(bx, by)

I want to calculate coordinate of point T(?, ?).

Comment: There are, in general, four solutions.

Comment: Ok, Can you please add solutions? It may be simple but I don't have any solution now.  Thank you @GerryMyerson

Comment: can you please add your four  solutions? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Here's a start: I'm going to change the letters. 

We're given points $R=(a,b)$ and $S=(c,d)$, and we're given lengths $RT=e$ and $ST=f$. Let $T=(x,y)$. Then $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=e^2$ and $(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=f^2$. So $$x=a\pm\sqrt{e^2-(y-b)^2}=c\pm\sqrt{f^2-(y-d)^2}$$

Comment: Draw a circle where OP the diameter. You have, to the best of my understanding, only two solutions - one above and the other below OP, intersections with the circle in your drawing.

Comment: You may also draw a circle with PT as radius.

Comment: But after drawing circle using either with diameter OP or PT how can I find Point T? I need to find tangent point T. @Moti

Comment: It is the intersection of the two circles. And do not worry it will be tangent:)